# PyGame: Two Sprites In Same List Collide

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame

In a game I am making I am trying to make enemies in the same list not collide with each other. The code I have used to try and get this to work is here:

```
for m in self.meteors:
    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(m, m):
        self.velX = 0
    else:
        self.velY = 0
```

I don't know why this won't work. It is asking if the two meteors have collide and is stopping there X Velocity or Y Velocity. Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass `m` to the collision function twice? Should one of them be `self`?

Comment: what it is doing, is checking if the same meteor occupies the same space, and if so, it sets its velX to 0. This will never reach velY since the same object will collide with itself. Could you elaborate what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to stop the meteors colliding with eachother but carry on moving in the other direction so if it has collided with the top/bottom of a meteor it will only move the opposite direction or move on the X Velocity.

Comment: If I do self I get an error about rect so I think it must be (m, m)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using a double loop?

```
for index1, meteor1 in enumerate(self.meteors):
    for index2, meteor2 in enumerate(self.meteors):
        if index1 != index2:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(meteor1, meteor2):
                self.velX = 0
            else:
                self.velY = 0
```

Comment: But I just read the top. I am using more than 1 meteor. SO wouldn't I have to do that for every meteor?

Comment: The first loop iterates through your meteors, the second loops through them again, checks to make sure you're not checking the same meteor against itself, then checks for collision. The rest is your code.

Comment: Ok thank you for clearing that for me. Will now try.